# How to get the only OTP number from the OTP message send by the server in android?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, broadcastreceiver, one-time-password

I have a Forgot Password page. i want to when the otp message comes it reads the otp number and verify.But in my case OTP message reads but i want only OTP number.
Like example My OTP message is :- 9563 is your OTP for Reset Password for your app. Treat this as a confidential. i read this message by the help of this class.but i want to get only OTP number like (9563).not the whole message.Can anyone tell me how can i do this ??

This is the class by which i read the otp message.

```
    public class IncominMsg extends BroadcastReceiver {

    final SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
    Context mContext;
    Object[] pdusObj;
    String message;


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


        final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();


        try {
            if (bundle != null) {
                pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                SmsMessage[] smsMessages = new SmsMessage[pdusObj.length];

                for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {
                    smsMessages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);

                    message = smsMessages[i].getDisplayMessageBody();
                    Log.e("message..", message);
                }


                Pattern generalOtpPattern = Pattern.compile(message);
                Matcher generalOtpMatcher = generalOtpPattern.matcher(smsMessages[0].getMessageBody().toString());

                if (generalOtpMatcher.find()) {
                    String otp = generalOtpMatcher.group(1);//this is only your OTP code


                }


            }


        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }


}
```

I get the message and print in the logcat.but I want only OTP number not the whole message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this it may be help to you

```
public static String GENERAL_OTP_TEMPLATE = "Your verification code: (.*).";

SmsMessage[] message = new SmsMessage[objectArray.length];
for (int i = 0; i < objectArray.length; i++) {
 message[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) objectArray[i]);

}
Pattern generalOtpPattern = Pattern.compile(GENERAL_OTP_TEMPLATE);
Matcher generalOtpMatcher = generalOtpPattern.matcher(message[0].getMessageBody().toString());

if (generalOtpMatcher.find()) {
   String otp = generalOtpMatcher.group(1);//this is only your OTP code

}
```

> make GENERAL_OTP_TEMPLATE is as per you message content and than after check
>   it.

Comment: Dear sir,This code is not working. i update my code please check if i am doing some thing wrong.

Comment: sorry ! i did not get you. can you please explain me ??

Comment: ok..let's try..
If your message content like `9563 is your OTP for Reset Password for your app. Treat this as a confidential` than your `GENERAL_OTP_TEMPLATE` is like  
`(.*) is your OTP for Reset Password for your app. Treat this as a confidential`
,
here (.*) means any type of OTP means that is dynamic part.

Comment: and change this line `Pattern generalOtpPattern = Pattern.compile(GENERAL_OTP_TEMPLATE); ` instead of `Pattern generalOtpPattern = Pattern.compile(message);`

Comment: happy to know..always wc @LoveAndroid

Comment: One more help i want to send the data(OTP number) in the activity.i tried shared prefernce and interface but it did not work.how can i set the otp number on the edittext and verify it.

Comment: for that you can Use `LocalBroadcastManager` to send OTP in your `Activity` please refer https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802157/how-to-use-localbroadcastmanager

Comment: @ Abhishek Patel Dear sir i need your help . if you are free then give me answer asap. my problem is that when i send the otp to another number by your code it takes the last OTP it received on the device.but when i send the OTP to another number i want that  it does not take the OTP of the last message in the phone .how can i stop this to take OTP of the last message when i send the OTP to another device. please help  me.